# Problem with LockerService and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

I have a custom component and when I try to use the following code:

Component.cmp

```
<aura:component implements='forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes' access='global'>
      <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.executeComponentInitilization}"/>
</aura:component>
```

ComponentController.js

```
({
    executeComponentInitilization : function(component, event, helper) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();     
        req.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
            // XMLHttpRequest.HEADERS_RECEIVED
            if (req.readyState == 2) {
                req.responseType = "document";
                // XMLHttpRequest.DONE
            } else if (req.readyState == 4) {
                if (req.status === 200) {                    
                    console.log(req.response);
                    debugger;
                } else {
                    // Something went wrong.
                    debugger;
                }
            }
        };

        req.open('GET', 'https://anHTMLpage.com'); // used https://sitepreview.na40.force.com for tests
        req.send(null);
    }
})
```

When LockerService is off, I am able to get a nice and sweet `Document` DOM object for the `XMLHttpRequest.response` when the `responseType` is `document`, but when LockerService is enabled, I only get an `Object` with a `toString()` method that returns:
 `"SecureObject: [object HTMLDocument]{ key: {"namespace":"mynamepsace"} }"`

Is this a bug? If so, will it be fixed in Summer 17? I tried to use the `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument` but it creates a `document` DOM without the right LockerService key/namespace.

Comment: This will have similar behavior in Summer '17. What to do with these dynamically created `document` objects is a non-trivial problem. If you need this behavior please bring it up through a more "official" SFDC channel like a customer case.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, read [Introducing The LockerService For Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html) and the more recent [LockerService and Lightning Container Component: Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html). By design, access to the underlying DOM (and objects like XMLHttpRequest) is replaced by access through [Secure JavaScript objects](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/tree/9fdc047d9877327902296feb0cf04822fed3f653/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker) to accomplish the security goals of the platform. This is not something that will go away.

This [Locker Service API Viewer](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV) suggests that the majority of functions are not blocked, and in theory most JavaScript code should continue to work assuming it is using mainstream JavaScript features. (Best not to assume though: test to find out.)

Do you have a specific problem with your code? If so please edit your question to provide more details in regards to your problem.

Comment: Hi @Keith C, yes I am aware of all those, but LockerService should simply parse the `req.response` to an actual secured DOM Document. Now it fails completely to parse the response and returns a very incomplete object. I tried to update my question to reflect that

Comment: @Marc-AntoineVeilleux Have you tried invoking the normal DOM functions to see if they are supported? Also with "Enable Debug Mode" checked for Lightning Components in Setup you should be able to step into the platform code and see what is going on - commented source at [foprcedotcom/aura/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker/](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/tree/8854d78efe0ab833c2af86008b6bc6ffabaefc21/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker). As old questions tend not to get answered, you might consider asking a more explicit question that includes anything new you have discovered.

Comment: From what I can see, when we pass a `Dom Document` to the SecureObject constructor, it simply ignore every property except the `toString` method.